# Knapp example of the Strichartz estimates for a solution to wave equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, strichartz-estimates

I am trying to prove that the conditions of the Strichartz estimates of the homogeneous wave equation,
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
(\partial_{tt}-\Delta)u=0,\\
u(0,x)=f(x),\\
\partial_tu(0,x)=g(x),
\end{cases}
\end{align}
is necessary. That is to say,

> Let $u:\mathbb{R}^{1+n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a solution to the homogeneous wave equation and $s\le0$, $2\le q \le \infty$ and $2\le r < \infty$. If $u$ satisfies the following the Strichartz estimates,
> \begin{equation}
> \|u\|_{L_t^q L_x^r}
> \lesssim
> \|f\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\|g\|_{\dot{H}^{s-1}}
> \end{equation}
> where $\dot{H}^{s}$ denotes homogeneous Sobolev space. Then, the conditions are
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{q}+\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n}{2}-s \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{2}{q}+\frac{n-1}{r}\leq \frac{n-1}{2}.
> \end{equation}

The first condition can be shown by using scaling argument, but my purpose is second one. To show this, I found an example, called Knapp counterexample, in Exercise 2.43 of the book, *Nonlinear Dispersive Equations Local and Global Analysis* written by Terence Tao,
\begin{equation}
u(t,x)=\int_{1\le\xi_1\le2; |\xi_2|,...,|\xi_n|\le\varepsilon}e^{ix\cdot \xi}e^{it|\xi|}d\xi
\end{equation}
where $0<\epsilon<1$.
According to this book, $u(t,x)$ is comparable to $\varepsilon^{n-1}$ (i.e. $c\varepsilon^{n-1} \le |u(t,x)|\le C\varepsilon^{n-1} $ for some $c$ and $C$, we denote $|u(t,x)|\sim \varepsilon$)
whenever $|t| \ll 1/\varepsilon, |x_1-t|\ll \varepsilon$ and $|x_2|,...,|x_n|\ll 1$.
And it would be used to show my question.

I proved already that $u(t,x)$ is comparable to $\varepsilon^{n-1}$ using direct calculation.
In order to prove that the second condtion holds, I tried to show that
$\varepsilon^{\alpha} \leq \|u\|_{L_t^q L_x^r} \lesssim
\|u(0,\cdot)\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\|\partial_t u(0,\cdot)\|_{\dot{H}^{s-1}} \leq \varepsilon^{\beta}$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are some numbers depending on $q,r,n$ satisfying $\varepsilon^{\alpha} \le \varepsilon^{\beta}$ which yield the condition. However, I am failing it to find that $\alpha, \beta$. Can anyone advise me?